# Why does this variable not get assigned inside this conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a variable that should have a value assigned to it based on window width. Width conditional statement works (checked with console.log). Adding class works as well if variable is declared and assigned a value outside the conditional statement. But nothing works if variable is inside that if statement. What am i missing?

```
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        var stickywidth = 200;
    } else {
        var stickywidth = 500;
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() === stickywidth) { 
            $('.sticky').addClass('opensticky');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Interesting! can you discuss a little further?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used to not to use the var inside the `if` statement .. so I believe that always something wrong will happen with the `Scope` .. so (if me) I'll define `var` `stickywidth = 0` outside the if statement then update the variable inside the if statement without `var` or I use it with a ternary operator:

```
var stickywidth = $(window).width() < 960 ? 200 : 500;
```

Comment: Consider explaining what the issue was in OP's attempt, to which this is a solution.

Comment: Yep. That worked. What was wrong with my code, though?

Comment: @Samij I used to not to use the `var` inside the if statement .. so I believe that always something wrong will happen with this .. so (if me) I'll define `var stickywidth = 0` outside the if statement then update the variable inside the if statement without `var` or I use it something like my answer above

Comment: i see. Thanks!!